Publish error for android cannot find file Release/net8.0-android/android-arm/linked/shrunk/_Microsoft.Android.Resource.Designer.dll
I have a .NET 8.0 MAUI app that I am trying to publish for Google store. The app will compile and run successfully in debug mode but when I try to build the .aab I get the following error:
error XABBA7023: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path '/Users/me/Projects/myproject/aspnet-core/src/MyProject.Maui/obj/Release/net8.0-android/android-arm/linked/shrunk/_Microsoft.Android.Resource.Designer.dll'.
There is no directory below android-arm.
Any help would be appreciated.

Compare your settings with this

AndroidManifest.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:versionCode="10"
          android:versionName="V.10"
          package="com.companyname.my_app">

  <application android:allowBackup="true"
               android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
               android:label="My App"
               android:icon="@mipmap/appicon">
  </application>

  <!--*******************************************-->
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="34" />
  <!--*******************************************-->

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID" tools:node="remove" />

</manifest>

Project properties:
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>net8.0-android</TargetFrameworks>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <RootNamespace>MyNameSpace</RootNamespace>
    <UseMaui>true</UseMaui>
    <SingleProject>true</SingleProject>
    <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'android'">21.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
    
</PropertyGroup>

<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Release|net8.0-android|AnyCPU'">
  <PublishTrimmed>False</PublishTrimmed>
  <RunAOTCompilation>False</RunAOTCompilation>
  <DebugType>portable</DebugType>
  <Optimize>False</Optimize>
  <WarningLevel>7</WarningLevel>
  <Debugger>Xamarin</Debugger>
</PropertyGroup>


To enable debugger in Release Mode:
Prject Properties > Android > Developer instrumentation > check Release & net8.0-android

Update (20.06.2024) | Current packages from OP comment
<ItemGroup>

  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Maui.Controls" Version="8.0.40" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility" Version="8.0.40" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="8.0.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Syncfusion.Maui.PdfViewer" Version="26.1.35" />
  <PackageReference Include="CommunityToolkit.Mvvm" Version="8.2.2" />
  <PackageReference Include="CommunityToolkit.Maui" Version="9.0.1" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="8.0.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Embedded" Version="8.0.6" /> 
  <PackageReference Include="IdentityModel.OidcClient" Version="6.0.0" /> 
  <PackageReference Include="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" Version="7.6.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="UraniumUI.Icons.MaterialIcons" Version="2.8.1" /> 
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Maui.Controls" Version="8.0.7" />
  <PackageReference Include="Sentry" Version="4.7.0" /> 
  <PackageReference Include="Volo.Abp" Version="8.1.4" /> 
 
</ItemGroup>


I made adjustments to the AndroidManifest.xml file by adding the reference to the xmlns:tools... in the manifest section and also added the line to remove the AD_ID. I also added the elements in the Property Group for the Release section of the Android configuration. I was able to generate a .aab file and sign it and publish it to the play store. However, the app crashes immediately after displaying the splash screen. The app works perfectly when compiled and run in debug mode, but fails once published.

it's better to create a new question to allow answers focus on the that issue , firstly,  don't waste your time by uploading and signing,  run the app on simulator on release mode, you can enable debug as well but I forgot it now

You can test it on your real Android phone by USB

For some reason it won't debug on the phone when it is in release mode, even though I have the settings in the .csproj file as you suggested with the Debugger switches set. Is there a trick to it?

it won't debug on the phone when it is in release mode Open project Properties > Android > Developer instrumentation > check Release & net8.0-android

I fully enabled debugging in the release version of the app and the app runs without crashing. But as soon as I remove the debug options it once again crashes after the splash screen. I cannot submit an .aab that has debug symbols in it, so I'm stuck. Again.

@DavidRutter, update your packages to the latest version, replace your PackageReference version you have in your project with the version on this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/78596758/3392605

I've updated the package and ensured the PackageReference section has the right values and now I get these two errors: CSC : error CS2044: /sourcelink switch is only supported when emitting PDB.
CSC : error CS2045: /embed switch is only supported when emitting a PDB.

Please list all PackageReference in your question, I will try them to check if  there is any version conflict







First half
Second half  




Also includes references to Volo.Abp modules version 8.1.4

One other note. I have 2 different .NET 8.0 MAUI projects, both compile and run successfully in iOS but will not compile / run in release mode for Android. Both are build on Abp.io commercial 81.4 framework.

I've created a new MAUI App using your packages, I tested it on Android on both modes no issue. Is the current state? iOS OK , Android Release Not Ok

Was the project created with Abp.io commercial? I created a new solution with Abp.io commercial, updated all of the packages and ran the android project in release mode. This worked. I then used Abp.io's suite to add classes and the corresponding services and tried to run the android app again and it now will compile but hangs after the splash screen. ugh

I'm sorry I've not used Abp.io commercial before , I suggest you to create a separate question that focuses on that Abp.io
